How to translate or apply force to a single link in a model in Ignition Gazebo Fortress?
I have a model with multiple links and I would like to move one link to a particular pose either in translate mode or by applying forces. How to do it in Ignition Fortress ?
I saw the tutorials. It explains how to do it in translate mode for the whole model and not the link - https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/manipulating_models . I would like to know it for the link.

Have a look at the apply_joint_force, apply_link_wrench and joint_position_controller demo worlds.
Documentation of the plugins can be found here, typically in the header files.

Is it also possible to read the applied forces or external forces experienced by a link ?

Maybe using the Force Torque system and/or the Force Torque sensor but I haven't used either of those and I don't seem to find any example worlds. Possibly the old Gazebo Classic documentation can still be relevant?

I just started using force-torque sensor. Unfortunately, there is no clear documentation. Do you know which tags to pass for a plugin in general. I see it is confusing as each plugin has different tags and I do not know how to find them in documentation and I looked in the source code, It was not clear to me
